# <input> tag will not work with my function

Tags: javascript, input

My HTML `<input>` tag is not working with my Javascript function.

```
<center>
<input type="text" id=user onsubmit="UserChoice" placeholder="Make your choice...">
</center>
```

```
var rock = 1;
var paper = 2;
var scissors = 3;
var spock = 4;
var lizard = 5;

function Game() {

    var ComputerChoice = ((Math.Random() * 5) + 1);
    var UserChoice = ""

    if (UserChoice == ComputerChoice) {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Its a tie! Your opponent also chose" + ComputerChoice;
    }

    if (ComputerChoice == 1) {
        return "Rock"
    }

    if (ComputerChoice == 2) {
        return "Paper"
    }

    if (ComputerChoice == 3) {
        return "Scissors"
    }

    if (ComputerChoice == 4) {
        return "Spock"
    }

    if (ComputerChoice == 5) {
        return "Lizard"
    }

    if (ComputerChoice == 1 && UserChoice == 2) {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="You won! The computer chose" + ComputerChoice;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your html code please. Thanks

Comment: Where is your input declared ?

Comment: `var UserChoice = ""` it is null or empty string  so no condition will check .

Comment: <center><input type="text" id=user onsubmit="UserChoice" placeholder="Make your choice..."></center>

Comment: Please try  `id="user"` instead `id=user`

Comment: It seems like the issue I am having now is that the computer is not receiving any information form the var "UserChoice". Because I am unsure where to connect it too

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai There is nothing wrong with `id=user`!

Comment: In the future, when people indicate you need more information in the question (as in this case with your HTML), please edit the question to include it, instead of adding it in a comment. (I have done that for you this time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UserChoice is never assigned a value

You are comparing `UserChoice` to `ComputerChoice`, but `UserChoice` is never assigned a value (other than an empty string). So that comparison is meaningless.

```
var UserChoice = ""
```

You need to obtain the user's choice from the DOM.

```
var UserChoice = document.getElementById('user').value;
```

### onsubmit is not being triggered

You seem to be misunderstanding the `onsubmit` attribute. It should point to a function to run on form submit. Also, it needs to be in the `form` tag, not the `input` tag.

```
<form onsubmit="Game()">
    <input type="text" id=user onsubmit="UserChoice" placeholder="Make your choice...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### The center tag is deprecated

Lastly, the `<center>` tag was deprecated as of HTML 4. To center elements, you can use CSS.

```
<style>
    center {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="center">
    <input id="user" ...>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is what you need:

1) I changed Math.Random() for Math.random()

2) Added a div to display message after comparison of values

3) I also added a line of code to get the value inserted by user

```
 document.getElementById("user").value
```

**Here's the Solution:**

```js
var rock = 1;

   var paper = 2;

   var scissors = 3; 

   var spock = 4;

   var lizard = 5;

function Game() {

   var ComputerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
   alert("Computer input was: " + ComputerChoice)

   var UserChoice = document.getElementById("user").value;

   if (UserChoice == ComputerChoice){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Its a tie! Your opponent also chose " + ComputerChoice;
      return false;

   } 

      if (ComputerChoice == 1){
      return "Rock"
   }

      if (ComputerChoice == 2){
      return "Paper"
   }

      if (ComputerChoice == 3){
      return "Scissors"
   }

      if (ComputerChoice == 4){
      return "Spock"
   }

      if (ComputerChoice == 5){
      return "Lizard"

   }

 if (ComputerChoice == 1 && UserChoice == 2){

     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You won! The computer chose" + ComputerChoice;
     return false;

 }

}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return Game()">
  <center><input type="text" id=user  placeholder="Make your choice..."></center>
  <center><input type = "submit"></center>
</form>
<div id = "result"></div>
```